# Can't browse to some folders with 'open file' dialog of certain applications

Tags: 18.04, permissions

Running Ubuntu 18.04, and I installed some applications (chromium, claws mail most recently) from the software center.  When I try to open a file from them (using the native file browser), it can't access many folders, such as /usr, /media, or any of my external drives (even though they're mounted).

I found that there's a permission for chromium in the software center to allow it to view some other drives, but still can't see /usr.  claws mail has no such permission.

How can I give these applications the same access that my user (and some apps like terminal and nautilus) have?  Preferably globally but if it has to be per app I'll just have to do it a lot...

Comment: chromium  from the Software Center is now a Snap, IIRC, as is Claws Mail. as a test, uninstall it, in the Software Center, then reinstall it with `sudo apt install -y chromium-browser`or alternatively, install Chrome without uninstalling anything and test with Chrome. If Chrome or the reinstalled Chromium works, then it's a problem with Snaps.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely using Snap versions of the software you mention. Snapo is an alternative software packaging system to the traditional APT system that Debian and its derivatives use for a long time.

One of the features of the Snap format is that applications run in a sandbox. This means they have a limited and strictly controlled access to the system. Snap software has default permissions, and that may include that the software can access your home folder, but not to system directories.

To make data available to such Snap applications, the data should be accessible  from within your home folder. You can achieve such accessibility by creating symbolic links in your home folder to data on other partitions/volumes or drives, or use "mount bind" to mount external data to a folder under your home.

More recent versions of "Software" include a "Permissions" button, that currently contains two options: "Access files in your home folder" and "Read/write files on removable storage devices".

Alternatively, you may opt for the "traditional" APT version of the software. In that case, remove the Snap version and instead install the APT version using "Software".

With respect to the future, you should realize that Ubuntu increasingly is moving to Snap as the primary format to install applications. In 19.10, Chromium is only available as a Snap. Even at the level of the command line, the distinction between the two packaging formats is being blurred. For example, a `sudo apt install chromium-browser` will now automatically install the snap.